# Need to changed markup with jQuery to work with thickbox iframe (2nd attempt)

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

This is a revised attempt at solving this issue. Excuse my noobness.

I have the following markup on a page of which I do not have direct access to...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('/BulkDiscounts.asp?ProductID=318&ProductCode=' + escape('LB30X40ES') + '&Orig_Price=22.95', 'Discounts', 'scrollbars,status,resizable,width=330,height=300');"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/buttons/btn_quantitydiscounts.gif" border="0" align="absmiddle"></a>
```

I need the above code to look like this so thickbox can open up a iframe...

```
<a href="/BulkDiscounts.asp?ProductID=318&ProductCode=LB30X40ES&Orig_Price=22.95&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=300&width=330" title="LB30X40ES Laundry Bags" class="thickbox"><img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/buttons/btn_quantitydiscounts.gif"></a>
```

I has originally thought of first adding a class of "thickbox" to the first set of code so I can target the first set of code easier and setit up so it can be used by Thickbox

Then what I would expect to do what to target the value in just after the productid= which in this case is "318" and put that in a variable, lets say `var proid`.

Then I would target the value in the escape('LB30X40ES') and put that in a variable, lets say `var procode`

Then I would target the value in `orig_price` which is 22.95 and put that is `var proprice`.

The do the same for height and width.

Then  build the new href =/bulkDiscounts.asp?productid='proid' + &productcode +'procode' + &orig_price + 'proprice' + &keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height='height'+ &width + width

The figure out how to update the old markup with the new markup/href.

This is the best that I can explain it

The reason I have to use variable (I would think) for productid,productcode,orig_price,height and width is because they change depending on what product page is loaded.

Note this code is not needed in the new markup...

'Discounts', 'scrollbars,status,resizable

Hope this makes sense? Anyone?

Comment: Not a single person has anything to offer?